# Show $H_n(X,A) \approx \sum_{\lambda} H_n(X_{\lambda}, A \cap X_{\lambda})$, where $X_{\lambda}$ are path components of $X$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

> Show $H_n(X,A) \approx \sum_{\lambda} H_n(X_{\lambda}, A \cap X_{\lambda})$, where $X_{\lambda}$ are path components of $X$.

The proof only says that these two theorems were used:
$$(1) : H_n(\sum_{\lambda}S_*^{\lambda}) \approx \sum_{\lambda} H_n(S_*^{\lambda})$$

$$(2) :H_n(X) \approx \sum_{\lambda} H_n(X_{\lambda})$$

but I'm having a hard time seeing how to prove this with these two theorems since the second theorem only seems to apply to a space, where the first theorem applies to complexes of spaces.

I can see that $$\sum_{\lambda}H_n(\frac{S_*(X_{\lambda})}{S_*(A \cap X_{\lambda})}) \approx H_n(\sum_{\lambda}\frac{S_*(X_{\lambda})}{S_*(A \cap X_{\lambda})})$$ and the second expression reduces to $H_n(X,A)$, but I don't see how $(2)$ applies here.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What are $S_*$?

Comment: For each component get a long exact sequence $\dots H_*(A\cap X_\lambda)\rightarrow H_*(X_\lambda)\rightarrow H_*(X_\lambda,A\cap X_\lambda)\dots$ and form another long exact sequence as their direct sum. Use theorem (2) on $H_*(X)$, $H_*(A)$, together with naturality, and then use the 5 lemma to get the result.

Comment: What do you mean by "as their direct sum"?  A long exact sequence of direct sums of each of the nth relative homology groups?  As in $\dots \rightarrow \sum_{\lambda} H_n(A \cap X_{\lambda}) \rightarrow ...$ etc?

Comment: Yes. In the resulting long exact sequence the middle term in each 5-term exact subsequence is $\Sigma_\lambda H_*(X_\lambda,A\cap X_\lambda)$ and the 5-lemma now tells you that is is isomorphic to $H_*(X,A)$.